# ESP8266 won't wake up from deep sleep

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-ide, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

Here is my code from of a project where I can to control a servo motor. I have tried to use deep sleep because I'll use a battery. But looking at my serial monitor, I have this message, and i can't access my web server.

> ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
>
> Connecting to Louise
>
> WiFi connected
>   Web Server Started
>   You can connect to the Server here: http://192.168.0.102
>   Going into deep sleep for 20 seconds
>   {l
>
> WiFi connected
>   Web Server Started
>   You can connect to the Server here: http://192.168.0.102
>   Going into deep sleep for 20 seconds
>   {l
>
> WiFi connected
>   Web Server Started
>   You can connect to the Server here: http://192.168.0.102
>   Going into deep sleep for 20 seconds
>   {l

What is wrong with my code?

```cpp
#include "ESP8266WiFi.h" // WiFi Library
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Servo.h>  // Include the Servo library

const char* ssid = "Louise"; // Name of WiFi Network
const char* password = "passme"; // Password of WiFi Network
int firstrun = 0; // Check if system was just powered on
int buttonpressed = 5; // To hold which button was pressed on Web Page
int servoPin = 3;  // Declare the Servo pin
Servo Servo1;  // Create a servo object
WiFiServer server(80); // Define Web Server Port

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
  Servo1.attach(servoPin);
  // We need to attach the servo to the used pin number
  // Connect to WiFi network
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  // Wait until connected to WiFi
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(250);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  // Confirmation that WiFi is connected
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  // Start the Web Server
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Web Server Started");
  // Display IP address
  Serial.print("You can connect to the Server here: ");
  Serial.print("http://");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Going into deep sleep for 20 seconds");
  ESP.deepSleep(20e6); // 20e6 is 20 microseconds
}

void loop() {
  // Check if someone is connected
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (!client) {
    return;
  }
  // Read which button was pressed on the Web Page
  String request = client.readStringUntil('\r');
  // Light up LEDs based on the button pressed
  if (request.indexOf("/OFF=1") != -1) {
    Servo1.attach(servoPin);
    // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object
    delay(100);
    Servo1.write(-90);
    // sets the servo position according to the scaled value
    delay(1000);
    // waits for it to get to the position
    Servo1.detach();
    delay(1000);
    buttonpressed = LOW;
    firstrun = 1;
  }
  if (request.indexOf("/ON=1") != -1) {
    Servo1.attach(servoPin);
    // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object
    delay(100);
    Servo1.write(90);
    // sets the servo position according to the scaled value
    delay(1000);
    // waits for it to get to the position
    Servo1.detach();
    delay(1000);
    buttonpressed = HIGH;
    firstrun = 1;
  }
  // Display the HTML web page
  client.println("<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">");
  client.println("<link rel=\"icon\" href=\"data:,\">");
  // CSS to style the on/off buttons
  // Feel free to change the background-color and font-size attributes to fit your preferences
  client.println("<style>html { font-family: Helvetica; display: inline-block; margin: 0px auto; text-align: center;}");
  client.println("text-decoration: none; font-size: 30px; margin: 2px; cursor: pointer;}");
  // Web Page Heading
  client.println("<body><h1>Dog Feeder</h1>");
  // Create Web Page
  client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); // HTML Header
  client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
  client.println("");
  client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
  client.println("<meta charset=ISO-8859-15>");
  client.println("<html>"); // Start of HTML
  client.println("<style>");
  client.println("body {background-color: #ACAEAD;}"); // Set Background Color
  client.println("Button {background-color: #195B6A; border: none; color: white; padding: 16px 40px;"); // Set Background Color
  client.println("</style>");
  client.println("<h1>Dog Food Dispenser</h1>");
  if (buttonpressed == LOW) {
    client.print("OFF");
  }
  if (buttonpressed == HIGH) {
    client.print("ON");
  }
  client.println("<br><br>");
  client.println("<a href=\"/ON=1\"\"><button class=\"/Butme\">Liberar Ra&ccedil;&atilde;o</button></a><br />");
  client.println("<br><br>");
  client.println("<a href=\"/OFF=1\"\"><button class=\"/Butme\">Fechar</button></a>");
  client.println("<br><br>");
  client.println("</html>");
  delay(10);
}
```

Comment: You need to learn how to indent your code. Hint: ctrl-T.

Answer (score 4):

Your code in `loop()` will never run. Deep sleep on the ESP8266 (at least for the Arduino project) actually resets the processor on wake, losing everything but the RTC memory. So, when you call `ESP.deepSleep()`, a flag is set in the RTC memory, the processor will reset after 20 seconds, and next time `setup()` is called `REASON_DEEP_SLEEP_AWAKE` will be set as the reset reason.

Since you're trying to run a web server, there's not an ideal sleep mode for you that will keep your web server alive. Even modem sleep will require you to tear down, and bring back up your web server each time. This means your browser connection would fail, unless you caught the chip at the time it was awake.